# CreateReactApp: import javascript file

Tags: webpack, create-react-app

We've a module 'graphdracula' properly installed and used in our CRA application.

This module contains a JS file that we'd like to use:

> lib/algorithms/topological_sort.js

This file simply declare a JS function and does not export anything and neither register it to window:

> function ZZ() {}

Is there any way we can import/require it ?

Answer (score 0):

If there is no export (or lexical relation), there is no way you access them; from JS engine point of view a declaration that is neither exported or used in closures will be useless after the running that module and will be garbage collected in most cases; so basically is it the same if you want to access a declared variable inside that module like `var a = "foo";` think of them as private attributes that are only available in that module 
unless you make the them explicitly available to others either by exporting or assigning to global;